# How to scroll over the element container which is under an overlay like the top area of YouTube?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, overlay

I am creating an website in which I have to implement scrolling mechanism over a container. But a portion of that container is under an overlay. So scroll is working good but when my mouse cursor is over that overlay scrolling is not working. Though I have implemented it with JavaScript scrollBy() method. But it's not that smooth like normal scrolling. Is there any other way to implement it like Youtube has done?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by smooth; is this not smooth like you think of it?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#side {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px; /** THIS **/
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

#sidetop {
    height: 10vh;
}
#sidecontent {
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

#content {
  padding: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px; /** THIS **/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="side">
    <div id="sidetop">sidetop</div>
    <div id="sidecontent">
        I am a sidebar I contain links and stufI am a sidebar I contain links and stufffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuffI am a sidebar I contain links and stuff
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices.</p>
  </div>
</div>teal
```

Comment: Here when my mouse is over the sidetop the content scrolls just like youtube

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joel Peltonen. It helped to understand the mechanism. But when I modified the code a bit, with the position fixed I could not scroll on the red navbar area.

If I use position=sticky, then the scrolling is working on the navbar area.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: aqua;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.75rem;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #3d3a3a;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(214, 210, 210);
  border-radius: 100vw;
}

.container p {
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  background: chocolate;
  margin: 0 auto 2rem auto;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptates aspernatur autem, minima deserunt iure ex sint ea officiis sit, a eos esse culpa voluptatum error, excepturi exercitationem ut quo consequatur amet odio similique sequi. Aut labore
    animi maxime vel aspernatur sunt odio ex dolores architecto ut! Possimus perferendis doloribus expedita porro, quia accusantium odit nesciunt. Saepe non, nihil iure sequi ipsum magni repellendus labore debitis impedit tempora molestias nobis voluptates
    in illum. Eum, architecto. Ab nemo ullam illum beatae cupiditate in modi consequatur voluptas voluptate alias non, obcaecati, fugiat ea, quas tempore veritatis quam facere voluptatibus magni debitis ipsam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptates aspernatur autem, minima deserunt iure ex sint ea officiis sit, a eos esse culpa voluptatum error, excepturi exercitationem ut quo consequatur amet odio similique sequi. Aut labore
    animi maxime vel aspernatur sunt odio ex dolores architecto ut! Possimus perferendis doloribus expedita porro, quia accusantium odit nesciunt. Saepe non, nihil iure sequi ipsum magni repellendus labore debitis impedit tempora molestias nobis voluptates
    in illum. Eum, architecto. Ab nemo ullam illum beatae cupiditate in modi consequatur voluptas voluptate alias non, obcaecati, fugiat ea, quas tempore veritatis quam facere voluptatibus magni debitis ipsam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptates aspernatur autem, minima deserunt iure ex sint ea officiis sit, a eos esse culpa voluptatum error, excepturi exercitationem ut quo consequatur amet odio similique sequi. Aut labore
    animi maxime vel aspernatur sunt odio ex dolores architecto ut! Possimus perferendis doloribus expedita porro, quia accusantium odit nesciunt. Saepe non, nihil iure sequi ipsum magni repellendus labore debitis impedit tempora molestias nobis voluptates
    in illum. Eum, architecto. Ab nemo ullam illum beatae cupiditate in modi consequatur voluptas voluptate alias non, obcaecati, fugiat ea, quas tempore veritatis quam facere voluptatibus magni debitis ipsam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptates aspernatur autem, minima deserunt iure ex sint ea officiis sit, a eos esse culpa voluptatum error, excepturi exercitationem ut quo consequatur amet odio similique sequi. Aut labore
    animi maxime vel aspernatur sunt odio ex dolores architecto ut! Possimus perferendis doloribus expedita porro, quia accusantium odit nesciunt. Saepe non, nihil iure sequi ipsum magni repellendus labore debitis impedit tempora molestias nobis voluptates
    in illum. Eum, architecto. Ab nemo ullam illum beatae cupiditate in modi consequatur voluptas voluptate alias non, obcaecati, fugiat ea, quas tempore veritatis quam facere voluptatibus magni debitis ipsam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptates aspernatur autem, minima deserunt iure ex sint ea officiis sit, a eos esse culpa voluptatum error, excepturi exercitationem ut quo consequatur amet odio similique sequi. Aut labore
    animi maxime vel aspernatur sunt odio ex dolores architecto ut! Possimus perferendis doloribus expedita porro, quia accusantium odit nesciunt. Saepe non, nihil iure sequi ipsum magni repellendus labore debitis impedit tempora molestias nobis voluptates
    in illum. Eum, architecto. Ab nemo ullam illum beatae cupiditate in modi consequatur voluptas voluptate alias non, obcaecati, fugiat ea, quas tempore veritatis quam facere voluptatibus magni debitis ipsam?
  </p>
</div>
```